# Why the getter is return null?

Tags: android, kotlin, getter-setter, getter

Why the getter is null? something wrong with my code?

```
class ClassifyViewModel (): ViewModel() {

    private var mUri : Uri? = null

    fun setUri(uri: Uri?){
        Log.d("URIVIEWMODEL", uri.toString())
        this.mUri = uri
        Log.d("URIVIEWMODELSET", this.mUri.toString())
    }

    fun getUri(): Uri?{
        Log.d("URIVIEWMODELGET", this.mUri.toString())
        return this.mUri
    }

}
```

I wanna call the getter on fragment like this:

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
        binding = FragmentClassifyBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, container, false)

        fragmentClassifyViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory())
            .get(ClassifyViewModel::class.java)
        Log.d("URIWOIIII", fragmentClassifyViewModel.getUri().toString())

        if(fragmentClassifyViewModel.getUri() != null){
            Log.d("URIMASUKKKK", fragmentClassifyViewModel.getUri().toString())
            Glide.with(this)
                .load(fragmentClassifyViewModel.getUri())
                .apply(
                    RequestOptions().placeholder(R.drawable.ic_baseline_loading)
                        .error(R.drawable.ic_baseline_broken_image)
                )
                .into(binding.classifyImage)
            showImage()
        }else{
            showNoImage()
        }
        return binding.root
    }
```

and this is the setter

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY){
        fragmentClassifyViewModel.setUri(data?.data)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you set the value first and then somehow call the fragment, change

`fragmentClassifyViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory()) .get(ClassifyViewModel::class.java)`

to

`fragmentClassifyViewModel = ViewModelProvider(getActivity(), ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory()) .get(ClassifyViewModel::class.java)`

so your activity and fragment share same values...

There are other ways to do that,
[please check android developers link](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate)